# Django Form not showing, only the button (NEW)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

only my Submit button is popping up when i am trying to pass a form. 
I even tried just copying the code from the Django website... Still does not work for me.

This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms

class contactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=100, help_text='100 max.')
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    comment = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import contactForm

def contact(request):
    form = contactForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
       print(request.POST)
    context = locals()

    return render(request, 'contact/contact.html', context)

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'contact/contact.html')
```

This is my contact.html

```
{% extends "contact/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Contact</h1>

<form method='POST' acion=''> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='submit form'/>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I really do not know what is wrong with this code...please help! Thanks
ps: I am new to python, maybe i need another version?

Comment: change  `context = locals()` to `context = {"form":form,} ` and it should work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two views rendering the same template. One of them, `contact`, passes the form to the template. The other, `index`, does not, so there is nothing called `form` in the context and the result will be blank.